# Get all TFS work items I have worked with in TFS2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013, tfs-query

A work item is often ended in QA hand so its "Assigned To" field is normally a QA's name not the developer.

As a developer, how can I find all the work items I had worked on?

I tried  "History Contains Word @me", it returns far less items I expected.

Answer (score 0):

The best that I can see is the combination of

```
Changed By | Was Ever | @Me
```

OR

```
Assigned To | =  | @Me
```

The `Changed By` setting can return some chaff but will match your work for sure. You still need `assigned to` because you may not have changed it yet.

If you want to you can also add `History Contains @Me` to see the items you are mentions (by full name!) as well but that does not appear to match the names of the people who make the history entry.